# How to define a folder while run-batch from jboss-cli

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-cli

How can I define a folder (e.g. relative to `jboss.server.config.dir`) where the cli script lies while running `run-batch --file=path/to/cli/script.cli` in jboss-cli? Auto-completion of a command `run-batch --file=`  in jboss.cli shows that the `jboss.home.dir+/bin` is the default folder. E.g.:

```
[standalone@embedded /] run-batch --file=script.cli
The batch failed with the following error: : File d:\wildfly25\bin\script.cli does not exist.
```

Comment: Did you launch `jboss-cli.bat` from `d:\wildfly25\bin`?

Comment: Yes. P.s. ```[standalone@embedded /] run-batch --file=..\standalone\configuration\script.cli``` works fine, but the ```jboss.server.config.dir=jboss.home.dir\standalone\configuration``` may change and hence I want to define the folder relative to ```jboss.server.config.dir```.